# How can an <ul> have an even right margin?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

How can I get the buttons to the right to align vertically, i.e. have an even right margin to this `<ul>`?

A node in the list looks like this:

```
<ul style="list-style:none;width:100%;">
  <li style="width:100%;">
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td>Parent 1</td>
        <td align="right">
          <!-- delete button -->
          <!-- edit-button -->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- child-<ul>s here -->
  </li>
  <!-- sibling-<li>s here -->
</ul>
```

The apparent problem with my code is that I have separate tables on each `<li>`, and they are not the same width. How can I organize the list to make the right margin perfectly even?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant horizontal alignment of the buttons next to list elements.

To do so, you can set the size of first (main) *ul* tag, and then force *li* to take all width possible.

**Example .html:**

```
<ul id="mainList">
  <li>Parent 1
    <ul>
      <li>
        Child 1
        <b>EDIT</b>
        <b>DELETE</b>
      </li>
      <li>Child 2
        <b>EDIT</b>
        <b>DELETE</b>
        <ul>
          <li>
            Another Child 1
            <b>EDIT</b>
            <b>DELETE</b>
          </li>
        </ul> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Example .css:**

```
#mainList {
  width: 400px;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
}

li b {
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: right;
}
```

If you want your *#mainList* to have 100% width, you additionally have to reset *#mainList* padding to *0px*:

```
#mainList {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/linoskoczek/cfgeqbvd/2/)

Also a note here, that using tables to position elements in HTML code is an anti-pattern. [See discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html).